# Could you give an example of a sentence in classical chinese wherein 爽 is used?

Tags: grammar

I have some real problem understanding the semantics behind this word, I would be glad to see how this word was used in classical Chinese in order to get an idea of its original usage.

Comment: Consider consulting a source such as [Kangxi Dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/kx/723D.htm) for usage citations.

Comment: http://images.gg-art.com/dictionary/dcontent.php?word=%CB%AC&sub1.x=39&sub1.y=10

Comment: The Chinese Text Project at http://ctext.org/ lets you search characters in classical texts.

Answer (score 1):

爽

1. clear, example:(idioms) 神清气爽
2. wise, example: 兹心不爽，而昏乱百度。——《左传·昭公元年》
3. cheerful, example: 温豪爽有风慨。——《晋书·桓温传》
4. v. make error, example: 女也不爽，士贰其行。——《诗·卫风·氓》
5. v. break one's word, example: 郭伋还州，尚不欺于童子； 文侯校猎，宁爽约于虞人。—— 李商隐《为张周封上杨相公启》